# extract strings from a list based on another string in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list containing integers like this (not in order):

```
list1 = [2,1,3]
```

I have a second list like this:

```
list2 = ['Contig_1_Length_1000','Contig_2_Length_500','Contig_3_Length_400','Contig_4_Length_300','Contig_5_Length_200','Contig_6_Length_100']
```

These lists are from fasta files. list 2 always start with "Contig_", but may not always in a well sorted order. I'd like to return a list like this:

```
list3 = ['Contig_1_Length_1000','Contig_2_Length_500','Contig_3_Length_400']
```

list3 contains contigs whose number only appeared in list1.

How to do this in python?

Thank you very much!

Comment: This problem seems underspecified. Is it guaranteed that list1's elements will always be in numerical order, or could it be `['Contig_99', 'Contig_23', 'Contig_42'"]`? Is it guaranteed that every element of list1 will start with "Contig_"? Are we looking for elements in list2 that _start_ with an element of list1, or is it sufficient if an element of list1 is a substring of an element of list2? e.g. if list2 contains an element "foo_Contig_1_bar", does that count as appearing in list1?

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for pointing it out. I've edited my question. this time list 1 only contains integers. Thank you.

Comment: I notice that "Contig_5_Length_200" does not appear in list3, even though "Contig_5_Length_200" contains a 2 and list1 also contains a 2. Is this intentional? Is it reasonable to say that we only care about the numbers that appear immediately after "Contig_" in list2, and we can ignore the rest? If "Contig_12_Length_999" was in list2, would it also be included in list3, or does the number following "Contig_" have to be an _exact_ match for one of the numbers in list1?

Comment: Only compare the integers in list1 and integers between  'Contig_' and before'_Length' in list2. Do not check anything after 'Length_' in list2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary from the second list for an `O(n)` (linear) solution:

```
import re
list1 = [2,1,3]
list2 = ['Contig_1_Length_1000','Contig_2_Length_500','Contig_3_Length_400','Contig_4_Length_300','Contig_5_Length_200','Contig_6_Length_100']
new_result = {int(re.findall('(?<=^Contig_)\d+', i)[0]):i for i in list2}
final_result = [new_result[i] for i in list1]
```

Output:

```
['Contig_2_Length_500', 'Contig_1_Length_1000', 'Contig_3_Length_400']
```

Comment: Now that the OP has edited their requirements somewhat, I reckon this answer is the one that's closest to actually working :-) Just needs a new coat of paint to account for the fact that `list1` contains integers now.

Comment: @Kevin Thank you for pointing out the change. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: Thank you very much! Kevin and Ajax1234@Kevin@Ajax1234

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension like this:

```
list3 = [i for i in list2 if any(j in i for j in list1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to iterate over the two input lists, and see for each combination whether there's a match. One way to do this is

```
[list2_item for list2_item in list2 if any([list1_item in list2_item for list1_item in list1])]
```

I tried Ajax1234 's method of using re, blhsing 's code which is close the same as mine except it uses a generator rather than a list (and has more opaque variable names), jeremycg 's method of `startswith`, and bilbo_strikes_back 's method of zip. The zip method was by far the fastest, but it just takes the first three elements of `list2` without concern for the contents of `list1`, so we might as well do `list3 = list2[:3]`, which was even faster. Ajax1234 's method took about twice as long as blhsing 's, which took slightly longer than mine. jeremycg 's took slightly more than half as much time, but keep in mind that it assumes that the substring will be at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use startswith - it takes a tuple of multiple starting strings to scan efficiently:

```
[i for i in list2 if i.startswith(tuple(list1))]

['Contig_1_Length_1000', 'Contig_2_Length_500', 'Contig_3_Length_400']
```

Answer (score 0):

A pretty simple list comprehension like:

```
list1 = ['Contig_1','Contig_2','Contig_3']
list2 = ['Contig_1_Length_1000','Contig_2_Length_500','Contig_3_Length_400','Contig_4_Length_300','Contig_5_Length_200','Contig_6_Length_100']

list3 = [s for s in list2 for k in list1 if k in s]

print(list3)
```

gives an output of:

```
['Contig_1_Length_1000', 'Contig_2_Length_500', 'Contig_3_Length_400']
```

Answer (score -1):

try zip and slicing

```
list1 = ['Contig_1','Contig_2','Contig_3']
list2 = ['Contig_1_Length_1000','Contig_2_Length_500','Contig_3_Length_400','Contig_4_Length_300','Contig_5_Length_200','Contig_6_Length_100']
list3 = [x[1] for x in zip(list1, list2)]
print(list3)
```

Comment: Seems like this just does the same thing as     `list3 = list2[:len(list1)]`. In this case it returns the requested list, but changing the order of the lists will result in a different output.